# Define a global Ant tool in a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have recently started to write a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline (Jenkinsfile in CVS) with several stages.

I'd like to know if there is way to define Ant only once and then reuse the same command in all stages.

Instead of repeating bat "%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat the_ant_target_to_run", I'd prefer doing this instead: ant clean compile

```
pipeline {  
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                echo "Building application..."   
                bat "%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat clean compile"
            }
        }
        stage("Unit Tests") {
            steps {
                echo "Unit tests (JUnit)..."
                echo "Mutation tests (pitest)..."

                bat "%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat run-unit-tests"
                bat "%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat run-mutation-tests"
            }
        }
        stage("Functional Test") {
            steps {
                echo "Selenium tests..."
            }
        }
        stage("Performance Test") {
            steps {
                echo "JMeter tests..."
            }
        }
        stage("Quality Analysis") {
            steps {
                echo "Running SonarQube..."
            bat "%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat run-sonarqube-analysis"
            }
        }
        stage("Security Assessment") {
            steps {
                echo "Pen testing..."
            }
        }
        stage("Approval") {
            steps {
                    input "Is the build OK?"
        }
        }
        stage("Deploy") {
            steps {
                echo "Deploying to JBoss 7.2..."
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
        junit '/test/reports/*.xml'
            }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to Manage Jenkins section and then Global Tool Configuration

there you can add ant installation.

then in the pipeline add the line:
antHome = tool 'ANT' - the name you gave your ant in the configurations.

after it you can use it as a parameter

Home it helps

Comment: I already have it installed (name is "Ant installation"). Will try it and get back with an update.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what your are suggesting? When you say "you can use it as a parameter", do you access it using $antHome or ${antHome}?

Comment: def mvnHome
    stage('Preparation') {
        dir('./' + microserviceName) {
            deleteDir()
        }
        mvnHome = tool 'Maven'
    }
    stage('Build') {
        // Run the maven build
        dir('./' + microserviceName) {
            sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -s mvn_settings.xml -U clean install 
        }
    }